# Automatic Differentiation using foward mode on matrices

Tags: reference-request, automatic-differentiation, neural-network

Whilst googling I see *reverse mode* automatic differentiation (AD) tends to be used when optimising neural networks.

Would it not be better to use *forward mode* and treat your input as a single variable, then use matrix calculus to optimize the weights.

For example:

$$u_{1} = x$$
$$u_{2} = W u_{1}$$
$$u_{3} = \sigma(u_2)$$

with the tangents of the primals being

$$I$$
$$u_{1}^{T} \otimes I$$
$$\sigma'(u_2)$$

why wouldn't this formulation be used vs reverse mode AD?

I understand the scalar cases of automatic differentiation. In addition to answering the question, would someone mind sending some resources where I could learn to implement forward and reverse mode AD with matrices involved?

Comment: I do not understand your forward mode. If $\dot u_1=I$, then $\dot u_2=W·I+\dot W·u_1$ and $\dot u_3={\rm diag}(σ'(u_2))\dot u_2$. To get all partial derivatives, $\dot W$ would have to be replaced with a tensor of 4th order that represents the unit vectors (all zero except one entry $1$) in matrix space.

Answer (score 3):

When you *train* a neural network, you are optimizing the function whose inputs are the weights $W$ in each layer, and whose output is the total approximation error
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in \text{training data}} \|f(x;W) - y\|^2.
$$
(possibly with different norms, regularizations, margins, etc.).

This is a function with many inputs and a single output, exactly the setup where reverse mode is more efficient than forward mode.